# The meaning of sentence "Right to the point on both counts." in simple words

Tags: meaning

I can't understand the sentence "Right to the point on both counts." It comes from a [comment by user Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058044/is-the-javascript-regexp-implicit-method-deprecated#comment3131294_3058057) in SO:

> **Right to the point on both counts**. Thanks. I didn't like it either, but was looking for ammo to defend my point. Since one rarely types JS code interactively, there isn't much benefit to the short form. – Eric

I am not a native English speaker, so I have difficulty understanding the sentence above. I have referred to some dictionaries and translator, but I still don't know how to understand it? So I want to know its meaning in simple words.

I have known that the meaning of  "on both counts" is "for both issues", but I can't understand "Right to the point".

Comment: "Right to the point" = "Addressed directly/correctly". "On both counts" = "for both issues". Presumably, someone was talking about 2 things, and they got to the gist of both.

Comment: I think it's a clumsy/non-idiomatic usage, not least because of the semantic confusion which ensues if you stop to consider possible differences between the two referents ***the point*** and ***my point***. I suggest something like ***Exactly** right on both counts* would be less "awkward".

Comment: I read this as saying, “Thanks. The information you’ve provided gets right to the point (of the argument being made) on both counts. (There were apparently two things being alleged)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Seems reasonably idiomatic to me.  It is true that the idiom is somewhat ambiguous as to whether the statement is considered correct, or is merely addressing the issues, but I think that there are a few other rare cases in English where ambiguity can occur, and somehow we manage to live through it.

Comment: Where did you see this?  It looks pretty strange. // Who is @replies?

Comment: @Hot Licks: I think normally *to the point* means *[highly] **relevant***, and it usually occurs in imperative contexts such as *Please stick to the point* (don't digress). Clearly OP's cite is extending this to imply ***correct*** as well as relevant - which I might find more acceptable in other contexts, but in this *specific* one I think the disjunct between *to **the** point* and later *defend **my** point* is almost a kind of "zeugma". It's *English*, but not particularly *good*  English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - In my experience, "right to the point" implies an incisive statement -- the speaker being described did not weasel-word his statement and went straight to the relevant issues.  It *might* imply perceived correctness, but not necessarily.  I have, on several occasions, heard someone say something like "That gets right to the point -- but it's wrong."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [gymglish](https://www.gymglish.com/en/english-translation/straight-to-the-point):

> **to get straight (or 'right') to the point:** to address the main subject directly, without deviation

You'll most often see the phrase to describe someone who doesn't add a lot of extra commentary or rigamarole.

In the context of a StackOverflow answer, it means the poster answered the question quickly and without additional commentary or detail.

---

From [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/on-all-several-both-etc-counts):

> **on all/several/both counts**: in every way, in several ways etc

This means that the commenter thought the answer was short and direct for both relevant points.

Having read the linked StackOverflow answer, I'm not entirely sure where "both" is coming from since I don't see *two* specific points -- but that's what the phrase means.